# mvnpdf() yields SIGMA mustbe a aquare, symetric, positive definite matrix

Tags: matlab, gmm

I have a matrix:

```
sigma=[0.1085 0.1085 0.1085;
       0.1085 0.1085 0.1085;
       0.1085 0.1085 0.1085];
```

I am reciving the following errpr: `SIGMA mustbe a aquare, symetric, positive definite matrix` for the e line:

```
mvnpdr(rgb_pt,mu,sigma);
```

As best I can understand from here this unsweres the demands. Am I correct? If so what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `sigma` is not positive definite. To verify this, use the [code provided here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101132-how-do-i-determine-if-a-matrix-is-positive-definite-using-matlab).

```
>> sigma=[0.1085 0.1085 0.1085;
       0.1085 0.1085 0.1085;
       0.1085 0.1085 0.1085];
>> [~,p] = chol(sigma)

p =

     2
```